# Grab text on page and insert it into variable jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to target the text from the HTML below between the closing `</span>` tag and closing `</h2>` tag using jquery and insert the text value, in this case it would be "Hello World", into my `s.pageName=" "` traffic variable.

I don't know where to begin to solve this problem? Please let me know what info you need to help

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="portletTitleWrap">
    <div class="portletTitle">
        <div class="title">
            <h2><span class="siteTitle">Homepage</span> Hello World</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my javascript snippet that I would like to populate `s.pageName=""` dynamically with Hello World. This value will change from page to page which is why it would need to be dynamic.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
s.pageName = ""
var s_code = s.t();
if (s_code) document.write(s_code)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
var x = $('h2').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType !== 1
}).text();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/qdMzG/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help! this was more in line with what i needed since i could then use s.pageName = x to plug the textnode into the pageName variable.

Comment: @Evan.. Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You can select the span element and use `nextSibling` property:

```
s.pageName = $('h2 span.siteTitle').get(0).nextSibling.nodeValue;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCd6T/

Or:

```
s.pageName = $('h2').contents().filter(function() {
     return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s.pageName = $('.siteTitle').parent().contents()[1];
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/47hem/1/